# OpenGL ES 2.0 texture showing black on some device

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, overlay

I am loading overlay sticker to my image using OpenGL ES 2.0 it is working fine in some of the devices like one plus and mi max but it is not working in some mid range devices like moto g3.

I tried other answers from stack overflow but none of them seems to work for me.

Here is my code of load

```
public void load(int i, int j, int k)
{
    Utils.printLog(TAG, (new StringBuilder()).append("startX:").append(j).append("  startY:").append(k).toString());
    if(bitmap != null)
    {

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(33984 + textureId);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(3553, i);

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(3553, 10241, 9729);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(3553, 10240, 9729);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(3553, 10242, 33071F);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(3553, 10243, 33071F);

        imageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();



        Log.d("TAG", "Width is " + imageWidth + "H is " + imageHeight);
        int l;

        Log.d("TAG", bitmap.getConfig().toString());

        if(bitmap.getConfig() == Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)
        {
            GLES20.glPixelStorei(3317, 1);
            GLUtils.texSubImage2D(3553, 0, j, k, bitmap);
            GLES20.glPixelStorei(3317, 4);
        } else
        {
            GLUtils.texSubImage2D(3553, 0, j, k, bitmap);
        }
        l = GLES20.glGetError();
        if(l != 0)
        {
            Log.e("SubOverlay", (new StringBuilder()).append("load: texSubImage2D() ").append(l).toString());

            (new Throwable()).printStackTrace();
        }
        startX = j;
        startY = k;
        widthRatio = imageWidth / displayWidth;
        heightRatio = imageHeight / displayHeight;
        bitmap.recycle();
        initPos();
    }
}
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: No gl error? What is the size? Looking at the code I suspect that you never call texImage but only texSubImage. SubImage is for updating, texImage is for allocating. Try calling texImage with 0 first.

Comment: Same code is working in other devices.

Comment: Welcome to OpenGL drivers :) Every vendor might interpret the spec differently. So a good skill for writing GL code is to find a lowest common denominator. Just try calling texImage first - I actually thing that is correct by spec also.

Comment: This is not a site for free coding work. Just pay your freelancer to fix it.

Comment: I know how to code. On debugging I found out that error is somewhere in this code segment so thought that maybe some experts here will be able to help me out.

Comment: I think you are saying is to replace GLUtils.texSubImage2D with GLUtils.texImage2D which I tried and it is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149867/discussion-between-jack-stern-and-starmole).